# JavaFX: Best way to include somewhat complex animations into GUI?

Tags: user-interface, animation, javafx, fxml, gif

I am working on a desktop application with JavaFX.  As seen in the image below, I have an open space for a sort of mascot character, which I hope to give simple animations to.  They are simple enough that it would be possible--but incredibly hard--to make in JavaFX, but complex enough that I feel like I should use a different method.  This is my first JavaFX program, so my experience level is pretty low.  I am able and willing to make these animations in other software and create a gif or mp4, etc if necessary, but I'm just in the dark here.  I couldn't find much documentation.  Below, you can see the space I would like to fill with an animated mascot.  What method would be the best for this level of animation?

[image: A screenshot of one page of the application.]

Comment: Choose the fastest way. In my opinion using JavaFx to achive described feature is an overkill.

Comment: Just make an animated gif and display it, or simply use a `Canvas` and do your animation stuff there.

Comment: I agree Przemek Krysztofiak, JavaFX would be too much for this.  And Jai, some people say that gifs make the program lag?  @Jai Do you think this would be true for a simple animation that's maybe 300x300?